# Sass: How to get parent selector in hover

Tags: css, sass

### Steps to reproduce:

```
.root {
    .parent {
        color: red;

        &:hover & {
            &__child {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### What is actually happening:

```css
.root .parent {
  color: red;
}

.root .parent:hover .root .parent__child {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

### What is expected：

```css
.root .parent {
  color: red;
}

.root .parent:hover .parent__child {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

So, the `&` in `&:hover` is not parent selector anymore. How can I get parent selector ?

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is for concatenating selectors together when nesting so you need it only on `hover`. You don't need the extra `&`

Try:

```css
/* hover concatenated to 'parent' and the 'parent__child' is nested to hover */
.root {
    .parent {
        color: red;

        &:hover {
            .parent__child{
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is not what I want. It's boring to repeat parent selector in BEM